# How to add iBus to start up applications?

Tags: ibus, input-method

I use Keyboard Input Methods program for inputting Tamil. I need to manually start it everytime I need to use it. How can I add it to start up?

I don't want it asking me this everytime I start it:

> "Keyboard Input Methods (IBus Daemon) has not been started. Do you
>   want to start it now?"

and also this dialog:

> "IBus has been started! If you can not use IBus, please open System
>   Menu -> System Settings -> Language Support and set the "Keyboard
>   Input Method" to "ibus", then log out and back in again."

Comment: Have you tried setting the input method in System settings>Language support to ibus? It should automatically startup if the input method is set to ibus.

Answer (score 16):

You need to add `ibus-daemon` to your startup applications:

- Open startup applications from the power cog
  [image: powercog]
- Add `ibus-daemon`
  [image: add-button]
  [image: add-dialog]

Comment: oddly, I had to use `ibus-daemon --xim` and not just `ibus-daemon` for it to work.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to the previous post adding `ibus` to `Startup Applications...`, I used

```
ibus-daemon --xim
```

as in the file `/usr/share/applications/ibus.desktop`.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better way of enabling ibus should be the following

```
im-config -n ibus
```

In older versions of Ubuntu, the following command worked, but it does not work anymore in recent versions of Ubuntu.

```
im-switch -s ibus
```

There is no need to manually add startup entry for ibus-daemon

Comment: Can anyone explain why this should work? I don't see why this whole issue isn't a bug. It seems so obvious that once you setup your multi-input keyboard that you'll need it again without remembering to start something up manually.

Comment: `im-switch` is no longer available in ubuntu now (Checked in 16.04)