# Start ibus on start up

Tags: 12.04, unity, ibus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add iBus to start up applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135548/how-to-add-ibus-to-start-up-applications)

I searched many places and found this

killall ibus-daemon and then launch the ibus from dash

but i want to have the ibus launched during the startup. Is there any permanent solutionrt

Comment: This is not the same question about 'how to add to the start up'. I am sorry that I assumed,somebody else would have seen this issue.

I have already added it by 'ibus-daemon' in the startup options. But anyway it is not appearing. The only way for me is to 'killall ibus-daemon' and then launch the ibus

Comment: I have this same problem, but only if the account is a "standard account".  If the account is an Administrator, then the ibus icon is showing in the taskbar.  I also have the problem of needing to manually killall ibus-daemon and then re-launch if I want it to appear for a standard user account.

Comment: This a known bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/875435
Try adding ibus-daemon as autostart. If you cannot figure out how to do, ask in ibus-user.