# Ibus does not start automatically on kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, ibus, ibus-avro

I have to manually start ibus each time I have to boot in to my kubuntu 20.04. I have tried several methods including adding the `ibus-daemon` into my start up application. I also followed this links.

[How to add iBus to start up applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135548/how-to-add-ibus-to-start-up-applications)

I have also included these lines in my ~/.bashrc

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

and relogged in. Still it does not work out for me.
Anybody have a suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

To mention, I have installed ibus avro in my kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Does ibus open when you run the command `ibus-daemon` in a terminal? Also, try adding the "Input Method Panel" widget to your panel

Comment: yes, ibus opens , and could you tell me how to add the input method panel?? I cannot find that out.

Comment: I have added the input method panel. but whenever I close the ibus-daemon on terminal, the panel disappears.

Comment: I did not experience this issue in KDE Neon (based on 18.04). Could you edit your question and add the version of Kubuntu you are using?

Comment: Just to ensure, how did you add ibus-daemon to autostart? Did you create a new entry in system settings > Startup and Shutdown > autostart? Or did you use some other method? Also, try the following. Search for Input method in the menu, and choose ibus inside it.

Comment: I used the first command that you mentioned. it worked for me after I start it up this morning, but it did not work for me yesterday after logging in several times. do not know why..

Comment: Can you Bangla write with ibus-avro in Qt apps like Kate, Dolphin, etc.? In 18.04 one could not write with ibus in Qt apps due to a bug. Patches were released to fixed it, but it does not work for me in KDE Neon. I wanted to know if this works in Kubuntu 20.04 (because I am planning to upgrade to 20.04).

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: That bug ([bug #1844853](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1844853)) was temporarily fixed in Ubuntu after about a week.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson For some reason it does not work in KDE Neon (I once opened a github issue of `ibus-avro` regarding this), despite using version `2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6` of `libglib2.0`. But I guess it has been fixed in Kubuntu 20.04, to which I will upgrade soon.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: KDE Neon means that you have newer KDE/Qt stuff, so that may be a KDE/Qt bug which is not present in standard Ubuntu/Kubuntu.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: Please note that the IBus security patch, which triggered the issue initially, was disabled almost instantly, and since then IBus has worked also on Qt apps AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Those variables should not be set in `~/.bashrc`, since that won't make them available everywhere in the graphical environment.

To make IBus start automatically at login ***and*** set the appropriate variables correctly, open the *Input Method* tool and select "ibus".

Alternatively you can do it with this terminal command:

```
im-config -n ibus
```

(That also makes `ibus-daemon` in the startup application redundant.)

Comment: Can this be automated with the post-install script of `ibus-avro` (and possibly other ibus engines)? A lot of users face this issue. A lot of hassle and bug reports would not appear if ibus automatically made itself the default input method right after installation. Advanced users might want to use a different input method despite ibus being installed. But they can change that themselves, and the default behavior can be made more convenient for average users

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: You make a valid point indeed. It's actually an `im-config` configuration thing and not specific to `ibus-avro`. So far `im-config` has been disabled by default on Kubuntu (and some other flavors) unless you have a CJKV locale. Why? Because users who don't need input methods experienced other kinds of issues if IBus is launched and configured by default. But lately I have noticed this issue, and tend to think that we should change it after all so `im-config` is set to launch/configure IBus irrespective of locale. You may want to file a bug about it: `ubuntu-bug im-config`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: Your question inspired me to post [this topic](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/default-im-config-configuration/17136).

Comment: I would be happy to file a bug report. But I am somewhat unsure what to write in the bug report as I don't know the technical details. Shall I ask `im-config` to be enabled by default? Could you provide a link about the "other kind of issues" you mentioned? Suggestion: When a user installs an ibus engine which also pulls ibus, enable im-config with the post-install script of the ibus engine. Otherwise, no need to enable im-config.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: I no longer think a bug is necessary. Instead I wrote that discourse message to reach out to the maintainers of the affected flavors. I want their input before making the change. And no, I don't think that messing with post install scripts in respective input engine would be a good solution. Changing [this code](https://salsa.debian.org/input-method-team/im-config/-/blob/devel/default/im-config) is what I have in mind.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: This has now been changed, so as from Kubuntu 20.10 you'll normally not need to deal with `im-config`.

Comment: Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me with IBus 1.5.22 and Kubuntu 20.04:

`System Settings` -> `Startup and Shutdown` -> `AutoStart` -> `Add Program` -> Type `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon` and click OK -> In the `properties` window for the newly added entry -> `Application` -> `Command`: `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon -dr` (Notice the `-dr`. If I only use `-d`, it works at startup but not at login after logout) -> `OK` -> `Close` -> Logout and Login.